# How would I create a constant that could be one of several strings depending on conditions?

Tags: swift

I want to have a constant using `let` that may be one of several values.

For instance:

```
if condition1 {
   constant = "hi"
}
else if condition2 {
   constant = "hello"
}
else if condition3 {
   constant = "hey"
}
else if condition4 {
   constant = "greetings"
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this with Swift and the `let` feature. But I'm inclined to believe it's possible, as this is in the Swift book:

> Use let to make a constant and var to make a variable. The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I think when the book says "The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once." it's mostly implying you can set a constant equal to some function of a variable.. like `let x = 2*y`

Comment: Just add the line `let constant: String` before your if/else statement. Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356266/242933 explains further.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out in the other answers you can't directly do this. But if you're looking to just variably set the initial value of a constant, then yes, that is possible. Here's an example with a computed property.

```
class MyClass {
    let aConstant: String = {
        if something == true {
            return "something"
        } else {
            return "something else"
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: Agreed! This is great :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for variable which will be assigned later inside switch-case:

```
let constant :String

switch conditions {
case condition1:
    constant = "hi"
case condition2:
    constant = "hello"
case condition3:
    constant = "hey"
case condition4:
    constant = "greetings"
default:
    constant = "salute"
}
```

Comment: because a `let` declares a constant, which you can't assign a different value to after it's declared.

Comment: @JohnEstropia: `let constant :String?` declares a constant, but does not initialize it. The above code is perfectly valid, and a correct answer to the question.

Comment: There is no need to declare `constant` as optional, at least as of Swift 3. I can't speak to the version of Swift at the time this answer was posted.

Comment: I did not say vondra's code is wrong. I'm explaining why he got downvoted. Using an optional here is irrelevant to the problem because you can write the same switch-case code with just `String` and not `String?`.

Comment: I would upvote if you remove the optional as is not really relevant

Answer (score 2):

One option would be something like this, using a closure:

```
let constant: String = ({ value in
    if conditionOne {
        return "Hi"
    } else if conditionTwo {
        return "Bye"
    }
    return "Oops!"
})(myData /*needed for condition*/)
```

Or, for another twist, using generics:

```
func fancySwitch<S, T>(val: S, fn: S -> T) -> T {
    return fn(val)
}

let x: String = fancySwitch(3) { val in
    if val == 2 {
        return "Hi"
    } else if val < 5 {
        return "Bye"
    }
    return "Oops"
}

let y: String = fancySwitch((3, 4)) { (a, b) in
    if a == 2 {
        return "Hi"
    } else if b < 5 {
        return "Bye"
    }
    return "Oops"
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the generics option is doing? I'm a little confused after starting at it for 10 minutes.

Comment: I basically made a generic version of the `switch` statement that takes a function/closure which produces the value. It's arguably not much better than @0x7fffffff's answer (which just closes over the variables, whereas I take `val` as a parameter to the closure) but it's a neat little example of generics.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're looking for. In Scala and some other functional languages this can be done using the `match` statement (kind of like `switch`) because the entire statement resolves to a value like this:

```
val b = true
val num = b match {
  case true => 1
  case false => 0
}
```

This is unfortunately not directly possible in Swift because there is no way to get a value from a branch statement. As stated in the Swift book, "Swift has two branch statements: an if statement and a switch statement." Neither of these statements resolve to a value.

The closest code structure I can think of is to first use a variable to retrieve the correct value and then assign it to a constant to be used in any later code:

```
let b = true
var num_mutable: Int
switch b {
case true:
    num_mutable = 1
default:
    num_mutable = 0
}
let num = num_mutable
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the line `let constant: String` before your if/else statement.

Below, an excerpt from [Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3 beta - Swift Blog - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) elaborates.

> `let` **constants are now more powerful and consistent** — The new rule is
>   that a `let` constant must be initialized before use (like a `var`), and
>   that it may only be initialized, not reassigned or mutated after
>   initialization. This enables patterns like:
>
> ```
> let x : SomeThing
> if condition {
>   x = foo()
> } else {
>   x = bar()
> }
> use(x)
> ```
>
> This formerly required the use of a `var` even though there is no
>   mutation taking place. Properties have been folded into this model to
>   simplify their semantics in initializers as well.

I found the Swift blog post above from the article "[Let It Go: Late Initialization of Let in Swift](https://www.natashatherobot.com/late-initialization-of-let-in-swift/)", which I found by googling: swift let constant conditional initialize.