# Setting an immutable variable with conditional logic in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a super simple question on the best way (i.e. style) to do this correctly in Swift.

```
if a > b {
    let x = 1
} else {
    let x = 2
}
//then procede to use x
```

Obviously, this will not work, because the scope of x is only within each branch of the if.  But what is the preferred way to go about this, if I want x to be immutable?  So far, I have been doing this:

```
var x:Int
if a > b {
    x = 1
} else {
    x = 2
}
//then procede to use x
```

which works, but leaves x as mutable.  The next choice is to use the ternary operator as in:

```
let x = a > b ? 1 : 2
```

This leaves x immutable but leaves a bit to be desired in terms of readability when the conditions and resulting values become complex.  Also, using the ternary solution completely falls down with a more complex example:

```
if a > b {
    let x = 1
} else if b > c {
        let x = 2
    } else {
        let x = 3
    }
}
//procede to use x
```

or this:

```
switch a {
case 1:
    let x = 1
case 2:
    let x = 2
default:
    let x = 3
}
//procede to use x
```

Is their any way to promote the scope of a let outward one level, or some other way this type of situation is normally handled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I create a constant that could be one of several strings depending on conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132936/how-would-i-create-a-constant-that-could-be-one-of-several-strings-depending-on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `let` in your 2nd example:

```
let x:Int
if a > b {
    x = 1
} else {
    x = 2
}
```

As long as `x` is fully initialized in all paths, this works.

It works with the `switch` as well:

```
let a = 3
let x: Int
switch a {
case 1:
    x = 1
case 2:
    x = 2
default:
    x = 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also achieve it using class.
like this

```
class immutableVariable{
    private var value: Any

    init(newValue: Any = "") {
        self.value = newValue
    }

    func changeValue(withNewValue newValue: Any){
        self.value = newValue
    }

    func getValue() -> Any{
        return value
    }
}
```

and then call it like

```
let x = immutableVariable()

if a > b{
    x.changeValue(withNewValue: 1)
}else{
    x.changeValue(withNewValue: 2)
}
```

and access values using

```
print(x.getValue())
```